# Генерация случайных чисел в диапазоне

Tags: fortran

Только начинаю знакомиться с фортраном. Подскажите, как я могу задать равномерно распределенные случайные числа в диапазоне от a до b, причем диапазон может быть в области отрицательных чисел?

```
real :: x
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(x)
```

Этот код, возвращает числа в диапазоне от [0;1]

Answer (score 1):

1. Берете число в диапазоне от 0 до 1.
2. Умножаете его на `b - a`
3. Прибавляете `a`